# issues in customer registration form magento 1.9

Tags: forms, magento, magento-1.9.1

I need to change the theme of existing Magento 1.9 system everything went right, but I am facing some difficulties with customer registration forms.

I want to change the Signup form of the customer, the current theme contains its own registration form.  I want to replace the registration form with previously used template registration form, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You must have to disable your current theme customer module or you can take a backup of the current theme customer module and paste old customer module in your current theme.